# Covert SQL to Linq Query

Tags: sql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am doing my final year's project, I am new to linq as well. I have an SQL statement which i want to convert it to linq. I am currently using .net core.
I will greatly appreciate any help ,

```sql
WITH
    cte_company (CompanyID, CompanyName, CompanyNumber, IncorporatedDate, TOTAL_YEARS) AS
    (
        SELECT
            CompanyID,
            CompanyName,
            CompanyNumber,
            IncorporatedDate,
            DATEDIFF(YEAR, IncorporatedDate, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS TOTAL_YEARS
        FROM tbl_Company
    )
SELECT
    cte_company.CompanyID,
    CompanyName,
    CompanyNumber,
    IncorporatedDate,
    TOTAL_YEARS,
    CASE
        WHEN TOTAL_YEARS > 1 THEN (SELECT
            DATEADD(MONTH, 9, MAX(TaxReturnDate))
        FROM tbl_Tax
        WHERE cte_company.CompanyID = tbl_Tax.CompanyID)
        ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, 21, IncorporatedDate)
        END AS TaxDate
FROM cte_company
```

I tried :

```cs
var result = (from comp in this.AccountDB.TblCompanies
            where comp.CompanyStatus == true && comp.UserName == username
            join tax in this.AccountDB.TblTaxes
            on comp.CompanyId equals tax.CompanyId
            orderby tax.TaxReturnDate descending
        
            select new CompanyTaxInfo
            {
                CompanyName = comp.CompanyName,
                CompanyID = comp.CompanyId,
                CompanyNumber = comp.CompanyNumber,
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Linq-To-SQL/EF have a feature to let you run raw SQL when you need to. Use it. Converting working SQL of any meaningful complexity to linq is a step backwards.

Comment: What is wrong with what you tried? Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: I ran out of logic, I tried on SQL and the SQL works. but i am struggling to do the same in Linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the value read from tbl_tax is constant, which means it can be reduced to this:

```
var taxReturnDate = tbl_tax.Max(tx=>tx.TaxReturnDate).AddMonths(9);

var result = from c in tbl_Company
    let TotalYears = (DateTime.Now - c.IncorporatedDate).Days / 365
    select new 
    {
        CompanyID = c.CompanyID,
        c.CompanyName,
        c.CompanyNumber,
        c.IncorporatedDate,
        TotalYears,
        TaxDate = TotalYears > 1 ? taxReturnDate : c.IncorporatedDate.AddMonth(9)
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have following function and it gives an error when i try ro cast the object,I have made a function with the following defination  public IEnumerable<Company> GetAllCompany(string username) { }
its not allowing me to return company object . Another issue is , how to join Tax and Company Table, so i can get all the companines whether there is taxReturnDate  present or not. thanks i will really appriciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You could still use your SQL with EF and still get the same result
for example if you create a stored procedure for your SQL
you could call it as the following

```
var result = await dbContext.<Your-Result-set>.FromSqlInterpolated(@$"[dbo].[Your-Procedure-Name] 
                                            {your-parameter1}
                                            ,{your-parameterN}
                                            ").ToListAsync();
```